# How to merge multiple MIDI files into one?

Tags: midi, guitar-pro

I am working with Artificial Neural Networks, on a task regarding music generation.

**Given:** a collection of MIDI files (converted from Guitar Pro 6) where *ONLY* three tracks are used (per MIDI file): namely, guitar, bass, drums. For example, I converted 5 AC/DC songs from their Guitar Pro file, into 5 separate MIDI files containing only one guitar track, one bass track, and the drums track.

**Wanted**: ***ONE*** MIDI file (with the same three tracks) that is merged from all other MIDI files. To be more clear, in the example above I mentioned having 5 MIDI files of 5 different AC/DC songs. How can I convert them into ***ONE*** MIDI file that contains all those 5 songs, played consecutively? For example, if I play this ***ONE*** MIDI file, it would produce the sound of one song until its end, then the next song, and so on until the last song.

Ultimately, in order to access MIDI information in Matlab, I convert MIDI files into csv files. If it is easier to merge csv files (while making sure that songs play one after the other), then please help me with the csv merging.

The csv format is obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types

[image: csv format]

Comment: That format uses absolute timestamps, so you would have to add the length of all previous files to all times in the next file.

Comment: I'm under the impression that .mid files are a binary format, not a 'human-readable' one, so I assume the .csv output imaged above is the result of post-processing, right? In any case, if you have csv files like these, _if_ the header is consistent (i.e. the notes always start on line 7, and the tempo etc doesn't change), then concatenating these in matlab is very easy; it's simply a case of collecting the csv as a cell array, discarding the first 6 elements from all cell arrays except the first one, and then concatenating them together (e.g. with the `cat` function).

Comment: alternatively, you could use one of the many existing midi-to-xml converters, and parse the xml to your heart's desire using matlab's xml-parsing tools and some simple if-statements

Comment: but the problem is that, if I do it your way, songs will not be merged through time. MIDI uses absolute time, and in order for me to merge, lets say, two MIDI files into one, I need to add the last time of the first MIDI to all timesteps of the second MIDI. Thats why using a DAW is easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution myself: use a DAW, in my case, Cubase.

This will allow to easily play and manipulate MIDI files.

Source: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/combine-midi-files?newreg=8269c5b81e61461a9ede73e3880b6884